# Ubuntu isn't booting correctly

Tags: boot, dual-boot, lightdm

I've run a dual boot Windows 10/Ubuntu 16.04 LTS laptop for years. This morning I had it over on the Windows side and booted to Ubuntu (where I spend most of my time).

I log on and run updates while I have everything closed. Leave it to sit for a bit and comeback and it's frozen. Reboot and it reboots to the purple standard logon screen. No GUI launches though the background is mine.

Went to ctr+alt+f1, and it says 'Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04, not 16.04 like the logon screen said. It was definitely the 16.04 background. The computer can't find anything lightdm, or gdm. I also ran apt-get upgrade again hoping that it had interrupted and it didn't help.

I'm sorry, I don't know how I can paste code, since I'm back over to Windows to post this.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar happen on a dual boot machine once. I followed this [helpful thing](https://journalxtra.com/linux/desktop-recovery/fix-ubuntu-16-10-upgrade-boot-failure/)

To summarise:

Restart the computer and select your ubuntu partition
Keep tapping the Tab key as the computer starts. Tap continuously until GRUB Start-up Menu displays.
Select Advanced options for Ubuntu in the GRUB menu.
Select the last known good Kernal version used by your OS. Choose the recovery mode version of it. 
In the next menu, use your cursor keys to highlight in order:
Update grub bootloader. Press Enter.
Enable networking. Press Enter.
Drop to root shell prompt. Press Enter.
Continue the software upgrade when the shell prompt is ready. Enter the command:

> dpkg –configure -a

Restart the computer by pressing the keys Ctrl+Alt+Del if the system halts while dpkg is installing software. Restart the computer by typing sudo reboot into the command line if dpkg completes software installation properly and exits to the command prompt.
Try to load Ubuntu with a normal boot. That is, when the computer begins to reload let it load to the desktop login screen.